# mysql connection for python

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am getting an error when I run this command:

```
`python manage.py startapp polls`
```

the error is:

```
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/n/Virtualenvs/venv-python2.7-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 108, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/n/Virtualenvs/venv-python2.7-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.5-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 18, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/n/Virtualenvs/venv-python2.7-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/n/Virtualenvs/venv-python2.7-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

This is my `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'levigo',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'USER': 'root',
    }
}
```

When I run this:

```
pip install mysql-python
```

I am getting this output:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): mysql-python in /Users/nikhilesh/Virtualenvs/venv-python2.7-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

What am I missing out here??

I am running mysql through xampp -

```
/Applications/XAMPP/bin/mysql
```

Comment: Not entirely sure about this, but it appears to me that in your settings.py the ',' after 'root' should be removed? (I don't expect it to be related to your problem though)

Comment: @Dave It's a Python dict, so the trailing comma isn't a problem.

Comment: @Alasdair okay, thank you for making that clear :), what would be the best practice for this though? (as it looks redundant to me?)

Comment: Try reinstalling mysql-python or upgrading to make surethat you have the latest version: `pip install --upgrade mysql-python`

Comment: The output seems to say that it's already installed. Otherwise your question is slightly above my Python level.

Comment: @Alasdair: I had tried --upgrade. It says it is already upto date.

Comment: @Dave I recommend the trailing comma, it means you can reorder/add/remove lines without adding/removing commas. The one downside is that I write incorrect JSON objects all the time!

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you for explaining, and that indeed does makes sense to me! And I love that JSON joke that you put in there ;)

Comment: @Alasdair: What could be the problem here?

Comment: @phantomphoenix I don't have experience of xampp, or setting up mysql-python on OS X, so I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you get an answer.